# How to create a drop-down menu in div?

Tags: css

How to show the scrollable menu when passing the pointer over the div of the text <kbd>1x</kbd> the scrollable menu is displayed.

What I want to do is something similar to the following image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**My code structure:**

```css
.spdText {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 10%;
    color: #29303b;
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
}


.speed {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.speed:hover,
.btnSpd:hover .speed {
  display: inline-table;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  top: -170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spdText">1x
  <ul class="speed">
    <li>x3</li>
    <li>x1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show your li items over hover ?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER when passing the pointer through the text **1px** that contains the `div` I want to unfold the menu of `ul li`

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER something similar to the following [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gpwLsyxn/) but instead of the button I want it in a div

Comment: Maybe you could try to make it into a <select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Edit:
First you leave a space above 'spdText'. You position 'speed' over 'spdText' giving it a negative top value.

```css
.spdText {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 10%;
    color: #29303b;
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
    margin-top:5rem; /*  You leave a space above  */
}


.speed {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.spdText:hover .speed {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  left:-25px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
  top: -4.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="spdText">1x
  <ul class="speed">
    <li>x3</li>
    <li>x1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @SrMiguel If so, exactly what I wanted... But how to make it unfold up upwards?